# Connections to postgres database failure

Tags: node.js, postgresql, authentication

I am trying to implement an auth service using node-express-postgres.

I had the pool configed as such:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME, 
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: 5432
});

module.exports = pool;
```

I am trying to do the following call as a simple test for connection:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../db');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let temp = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM records");
        console.log(temp)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
});
```

When I send a post request to this endpoint my app crash with the following error:
**`Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string`**

I have checked all my env vars and they are correct.
Any idea why it is failing to do any operation on the postgres DB?

Comment: What gives `console.log( typeof process.env.DB_PASSWORD )`?

Comment: it returns a string

Comment: I suggest to implement connect method for your db in your db.js file,
so, when it's included in another file, i'll automatically run connect operation and then do other stuff

Comment: I am seeing the same error for pool.connect()

Comment: @nimrodfeldman Were you able to solve this error?

Comment: Getting the same error. Anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

It seems, that node didn't read .env file.
You can check it with

```
console.log(process.env.DB_PASSWORD);
```

It can be fixed with package 'dotenv', for example.

```
npm i --save dotenv
```

And then in first line in index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Answer (score 3):

For me configuring 'dotenv' resolved error

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your postgres password if it's correct. I had a similar problem while working on a mac, by default the
posgreSQL user is "posgres" and password is "root"

In my case I had something like

```
...

  USER: "postgres",

  PASSWORD: "",
...
```

which generated the error

Answer (score 0):

you probably should indicate your .env file location inside of the config

```js
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' });
```

[dotenv configurations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by updating npm script.

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start
```

Installed "cross-env" to set NODE_ENV.
If our code is not able to find .development.env file or unable to find password, then this error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the path in your IDE folder, when i checked, it was by one path below, so i moved it in the correct folder and boom, it all worked.